# Post checkbox values using MVC property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to pass the checkbox values to the controller on checking from a list of checkbox without using any submit button or any jquery Ajax? I just want to use only asp.net mvc property.

Comment: We are not clear about what you want or what you are trying. Post relevant code as well to get better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

As user1576559 sad in comment:

> I want to submit the form when I'll check or uncheck any of the
>   checkboxs without using any jquery or ajax

Here it is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home"))
{
    <p>Checkboxes:</p>
    @Html.CheckBox("chk1", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" }); <br/>
    @Html.CheckBox("chk2", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" }); <br />
    @Html.CheckBox("chk3", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" }); <br />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need to use `@Html.CheckboxFor(m=>m.PropertyName)` when you send the page to server then you get the updated checkbox status.

Comment: Yes..I know that.But it's only possible when I submit the form by clicking submit button.But my requirement is little a bit different.I want to submit the form when I'll check or uncheck any of the checkboxs without using any jquery or ajax.

Comment: @user1576559 without sending any request how the controller know that you have changed the check box status

Comment: Do you just want to submit the form automatically when the checkbox changes? In which case you can just use an event handler e.g.: `$("#yourCheckboxID").click(function(){$('#yourFormID').submit();}); ` or the JavaScript equivalent. You can't do this without JavaScript, but it will submit the form normally, not as an Ajax call.